# Obtain kernel logs in docker when a user space program crashes

Tags: docker, segmentation-fault

I am running program inside a debian-10 32 bit docker and the user program crashed throwing a segfault. I have compiled the program in debug mode and hence would like to obtain the stack pointer that caused the failure from kernel logs ( This is not a docker crash just a user program crash inside the docker)

Where to find the kernel logs in the docker ? or from the host machine ?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the kernel logs in **/var/log/** path, i'm not sure on debian but on ubuntu for example you can see it in **/var/log/kern.log**. i think it'll be easy for you to see it in your debian image.

Comment: I tried but can't kernel.log doesn't exist.

Comment: i meant that for example can tell you what you're looking for, but ok. take a look on /var/log/messages if not so please check /etc/syslog.conf maybe there you can see where the segfault logs go